# how to find a column name and value of a variable in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am not able to find the how to find a column name and value of a variable which is assigned in plsql procedure.

for example:

```
i_num_XXXX   IN NUMBER;
i_str_YYYY   IN VARCHAR2;
```

Comment: Search in code to find out how this variables are getting assigned.

Comment: What do you mean by finding a column name inside procedure? Do you want to know values from which columns of a table are assigned to these variables?

Comment: Hi Kaushik thanks for the response, yes I want to know values from which columns of a table are assigned to these variables.

Answer (score 1):

That would be

```
select * from user_source where lower(text) like '%i_num_xxxx%'
```